# Error while converting varchar(500) to float in sql server v2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert [Standard price] which is in varchar(500) format to float but I am getting error 'error converting varchar to float'.

Below is my query:

```
select IM.Material, CONVERT(float, Replace(Replace(IM.[Standard price], '"', ''), ',', '')) as colname from ItemMaster as IM
```

[Standard price] field contains (double quotes) and (comma) hence I am replacing them with blank before converting to float.

Is there any alternative approach need to try with SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE ISNUMERIC(Replace(Replace([column_name], '"', ''), ',', '')) WHEN 1 THEN CAST((Replace(Replace([column_name], '"', ''), ',', ''))   AS float) ELSE null END
from table as IM
```

or

```
Select Try_convert(float,Replace(Replace([column_name], '"', ''), ',', '')) as [Varchar to float]
from table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If there , in string, the ISNUMERIC can return 1 but cannot convert to float directly
you can convert to money first.

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('1,123,34'),CONVERT(MONEY,'1,123,34')--,CONVERT(float,'1,123,34')
```

---return ----
1   112334.00